# ZF2 - usage of partials in a loop

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a little problem with partials in ZF2. For example:

```
echo 'First table with data';
echo $this->partial('some_partial.phtml', array('data' => $data_1));
echo 'Second table, looks the same but with some other data';
echo $this->partial('some_partial.phtml', array('data' => $data_2));
```

First partial returns good results, that means table made from $data_1, but the second partial didn't made table only from $data_2 as I except but from merge of arrays $data_1 and $data_2. Why is it happen? And how to resolve this?

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the content of `$data_1` and `$data_2`. It sounds like `$data_2` is emtpy.

Comment: your issue is probably due to the implementation of the `Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer` merging both array `data` keys together (as it would be the same instance) I would start there and update your question with more info.